# WooCommerce Price Filter not working?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In my wordpress project, WooCommerce Price Filter is not working properly in sidebar widget.

Here it shows the price rang is between $0 to $1.  And slider not working properly.

How can I fix this. Please guide.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet on where particularly you're having trouble

Comment: @DenIsahac I am talking about built in  WooCommerce Price Filter widget.  Which displayed in sidebar like this. http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1498478924.png

Comment: Can you provide the link of your project?

Comment: Sorry, This project is not live yet, It is in my local system.

Comment: Then we won't be able to help you much then.

Comment: It's okay, brother. Thanks for your precious time. :)

Answer (score 2):

I were facing the same problem with the variable products. I have solved it by following below steps:-

**Step 1:-**
Read the whole documentation carefully and how to create the products or variable products

```
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/
```

**Step 2:-** 
Check the variation tabs of products and click on each variation types you can see it will expand and then add price there for all products then your price filter widget will start appearing.

For detail check below screenshot:-
[image]